# Redux: Accessing current state - best practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, flux

Here is something I don't understand about Redux. I have an app which goes through items. You can go to the previous item and to the next item. As I understand it, you are not supposed to access the current state in your actions.

As regards my app, I have an array in my redux state which holds all the ids of my items: `["3123123123","1231414151","15315415", etc.]` and I have a piece of state which holds the `currently selected item` (or better, it holds the *id* of that item). Now when the user clicks `nextItem`, I need to get the next item. My (unfinished) action look like this:

```
export function nextItem(currentId) {

  //my idea:
  //take the currentId, look where in the array it is, and get the position
  //increment that position
  //get the id of the next item in the array (at position: position+1)
  //update state

  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_ITEM,
    payload: item
  }
}
```

Similar things would apply to the previous Item action creator. However, I am at loss how to implement this action creator, without accessing my current state? Where and how would that ideally happen?

Comment: Actually action creator shouldn't do anything. It should be done by the reducer, that has a reference to current state. The action should be something like 'SET_NEXT_ITEM'

Comment: You can store at redux the index of current item

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I could do that, but wouldn't that mean introducing redundancy into my state, since I can derive / calculate the index by checking where in the array I find the needed id?

Comment: @R.Kohlisch I agree... I don't like the "index" idea also... you can use .findIndex() to find the index at render, or in your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you dispatch an action like:

```
{
    type: INCREMENT_CURRENT_ITEM
}
```

You can dispatch this from within any connected component directly:

```
dispatch({ type: INCREMENT_CURRENT_ITEM })
```

Or if you prefer to use an action creator, that's fine too:

```
dispatch(incrementItem()) // incrementItem() returns the action above
```

In your reducer, you have access to the current state, which is where you can increment the item index, without having to search for the current value in an array.

Comment: Thanks. `In your reducer, you have access to the current state, which is where you can increment the item index`  - but I will only have access to parts of my state. In my case, I need access to the state of a different reducer, in order to get the next id. How would I do that?

Comment: @R.Kohlisch it's difficult to give any concrete advice without being able to see a [mcve] but it sounds like you might want to restructure your reducers and decide whether to store the item ID or index, not both.

Answer (score 1):

I probably would add a component responsible of items id incrementing through the app

[image: Edit k0847p7k7]

```
import React from "react";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { nextItem } from "../redux/actions";

const ItemNav = ({ nextItem, items, item }) => {

  function setNextItem() {
    let currentItemID = items.indexOf(item) + 1;
    if (currentItemID >= items.length - 1) currentItemID = 0;
    nextItem(items[currentItemID]);
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      <li>previous item</li>
      <li onClick={setNextItem}>next item</li>
    </ul>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  items: state.items,
  item: state.item
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({ nextItem },dispatch);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ItemNav);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**The reducer** is a pure function](https://redux.js.org/introduction/threeprinciples#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions). The producer must receive
arguments of the same type,  the producer must calculate the new
version of the state and return it.  No surprises. No side effects. No
calls to the third-party API.  No changes (mutations). Only the
calculation of the new version of the state.

> Pure function - At the fundamental level, any function that does not
>   change the input does not depend on the external state  (database, DOM
>   or global variable) and returns the same result for the same input
>   data as a pure function.

In addition, if the values are in a different reducer, what to do?

**Action creators** - also pure functions, and for calculation we must
receive data from the store

**Component** - use business logic in the component bad practice

Remain **middleware** and to not produce many middleware it is better to
use ***redux-thunk***

In addition, a link to a similar question:
    [Redux: Reducer needs state of other Reducer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642726/redux-reducer-needs-state-of-other-reducer)

And the link to the first found project realizing this situation:
    https://github.com/rwieruch/favesound-redux/blob/master/src/actions/player/index.js