# Redux: Reducer needs state of other Reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flux

Say I have two reducers.

**Reducer No.1 : Currently-Selected-Item-Reducer**

```
state = {currentlySelectedItemId: 123}
```

**Reducer No.2 : All-Items-Reducer**

```
state = [{ id: 123, name: "John"}, {id: 231, name: "Jill"}, {id: 411, name: "Alf"}]
```

I have a simple React app and a React component simply displays the currently selected item. I.e., based on the id in the `currently-selected-item-reducer`, it find the correct item to display in the `all-items reducer`.

**Problem:**

Say the currently selected item is `123` and I want to go to implement a button which will always go the next item in the array. Now I need to find item `123` in the `all-items-reducer`, get its index in that array, and then increment it. Then my React component will do the rest.

However, this means that I need to access the array of the `all-items-reducer` in my `current-item reducer`. How is this possible? Or am I misunderstanding something here?

*PS: I would prefer to not introduce a counter in my `currently-selected-item-reducer`, since this would be redundant information: I should, in theory, be able to find the item position of the current selection by looking at the `all-items-reducer array` and do a `findIndex()` or something like that.*

Answer (score 9):

There are a few approaches you can take:

1. Combine the two reducers; one could argue that the two segments of state are so interrelated that one reducer should take care of everything.
2. Duplicate some data across reducers (obviously is wasteful, but if the reducers are truly very separate, a little redundancy might be warranted)
3. Let *your component layer* figure out what the next item is and dispatch the specific ID to select.
4. Use something like the `redux-thunk` middleware which lets you not-only dispatch a multi-action-creating action but also lets you query state.

Sample of `redux-thunk` approach:

```
function gotoNextItem() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { current, items } = getState(); // or whatever the reducers are called
    const index = items.findIndex(item => item.id === current.currentlySelectedItemId);
    const newIndex = (index + 1) % items.length;
    const newItem = items[newIndex];

    dispatch({ type: 'SELECT_ITEM', payload: { item: newItem } });
  };
}

store.dispatch(gotoNextItem());
```